# how to reach values in two dimensional array

Tags: java, oop

```
public class A6{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //String personInfo[][]=new String[][] { 
        String personInfo[][]={
                {"Anderson",  "Varejao",     "1125"},
                {"Giorgi",  "Tevzadze",      "1125"},
                {"Will",      "Cherry",      "1225"},
                {"Will",      "Iams",       "12245"},
                {"Lebron",    "James",       "6025"},
                {"Kevin",     "Love",        "2525"},
                {"Kyrie",     "Livings",      "454"},
                {"Kyrie",     "Botti",       "4544"},
                {"Chris",     "Mauer",        "425"},
                {"Mot",       "Daniel",       "125"},
                {"Viktor",    "Muller",       "145"},
                {"Kiamran",   "Chris",       "1405"},
                {"Zenia",     "Vaitehovic",  "1025"},
                {"Marija",    "Grabauskaite","1471"},
                {"Milda",    "Grabauskaite", "1000"},
                {"Dion",      "Waiters",     "625" },
                {"Dion",      "Malborg",    "6250" }
        };


        System.out.println("Peoples on the list:");
        for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < personInfo[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(personInfo[i][j]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------");

        //---------v XXX  - how many people have the first name XXX----------------

        String b = "v";

        if(args[0].equals(b))

        {

            System.out.println("Persons with entered name:");

            for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {

                for(int j = 0; j < personInfo[i].length; j++) {

                    if(personInfo[i][j].equals(args[1]))
                    {
                        System.out.println(args[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        //------vp XXX YYY - what is the salary of the person XXX YYY------
    }
}
```

I started to do new self control exercise. Here I have two dimensional String array which holds this information {"name", "surname", "salary"}. I already done one part of my exercise which counts how many people has the name that I entered into command line. Now I need to write a code for example: I enter into the command line Anderson Varejao and want to get result 1125. In other words I enter a name and surname and want to get a salary of certain person from personInfo String array. How can I reach and take a salary of person?

Comment: Please reformat your code this is really not readable at all.
However for your question: Just search for a person with a fitting name and print out the salary should do it, or? So copy your code from "searching a person" and just not print out the person but their salary.

Comment: Loop over the outer dimension of your array, and ....

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {
    if(personInfo[i][0].equals(args[1]) &&
            personInfo[i][1].equals(args[2]) {
        System.out.println(personInfo[i][2]);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

> In other words I enter a name and surname and want to get a salary of
>   certain person from personInfo String array. How can I reach and take
>   a salary of person?

name is stored in the first index and salary in the third index of the second dimension.
So you could define a `findSalary()` method that rely on that :

```
public String findSalary(String personInfo[][], String name)
  for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {      
      if (name.equals(personInfo[i][0])){
           return personInfo[i][2];
      }        
  }
   return null;
}
```

And invoke :

```
String personInfo[][]={ ...};
String salary = findSalary(personInfo, "john");
```

Note that using `String` to represent numeric things is probably not the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Split your search criteria by space and store result in array eg:result[2]

check a[i][j]=result[0]firstpart && checka[i][j+1]=result[1] second half then print the expected value

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use this way so here what you want

```
for (int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {
    if(personInfo[i][0] == args[0] && personInfo[i][1] == args[1]) {
       System.out.println(personInfo[i][2]);
    }
}
```

**NOTE** enter name and surname separated by spaces.

But if you want a good solution you should use the power of Object Oriented so 
make a class which can hold person information
like :

```
class Person {
    String name = "";
    String surName = "";
    String salary = "";
    //setters and getters here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With how you positioned your elements in the array, since the salary is always in personInfo[2], I'll just iterate the array one row at a time and check if the firstName corresponds to the element in peopleinfo[0] && lName corresponds to peopleinfo[1]. 
Looks something like this:

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

static String personInfo[][] = {
    {"Anderson", "Varejao", "1125"},
    {"Giorgi", "Tevzadze", "1125"},
    {"Will", "Cherry", "1225"},
    {"Will", "Iams", "12245"},
    {"Lebron", "James", "6025"},
    {"Kevin", "Love", "2525"},
    {"Kyrie", "Livings", "454"},
    {"Kyrie", "Botti", "4544"},
    {"Chris", "Mauer", "425"},
    {"Mot", "Daniel", "125"},
    {"Viktor", "Muller", "145"},
    {"Kiamran", "Chris", "1405"},
    {"Zenia", "Vaitehovic", "1025"},
    {"Marija", "Grabauskaite", "1471"},
    {"Milda", "Grabauskaite", "1000"},
    {"Dion", "Waiters", "625"},
    {"Dion", "Malborg", "6250"}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
    String fName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
    String lName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fName + " " + lName + "' Salary: " + salaryLookUp(personInfo, fName, lName));

}

static String salaryLookUp(String[][] array, String fName, String lName) {
    String salary = "";

    for (String[] row : personInfo) {
        if (row[0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && row[1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName)) {
            salary = row[2];
            break;
        } else {
            salary = "Not Found";
        }
    }
    return salary;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is wrote in C# , Hope it is helpfull...

```
string[,] personInfo = new string[,] { 
    {"Anderson",  "Varejao",     "1125"},
    {"Giorgi",  "Tevzadze",      "1125"},
    {"Will",      "Cherry",      "1225"},
    {"Will",      "Iams",       "12245"},
    {"Lebron",    "James",       "6025"},
    {"Kevin",     "Love",        "2525"},
    {"Kyrie",     "Livings",      "454"},
    {"Kyrie",     "Botti",       "4544"},
    {"Chris",     "Mauer",        "425"},
    {"Mot",       "Daniel",       "125"},
    {"Viktor",    "Muller",       "145"},
    {"Kiamran",   "Chris",       "1405"},
    {"Zenia",     "Vaitehovic",  "1025"},
    {"Marija",    "Grabauskaite","1471"},
    {"Milda",    "Grabauskaite", "1000"},
    {"Dion",      "Waiters",     "625" },
    {"Dion",      "Malborg",    "6250" } 
};

string FirstName = "Milda";
string LastName = "Grabauskaite";

for (int i = 0; i < personInfo.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if(personInfo[i,0] == FirstName && personInfo[i,1] == LastName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName + " Salary Is: " + personInfo[i,2]);
    }
}
```